# Can I hook into wp_update_core outside of the admin?

Tags: wp-admin, hooks, updates, core

I'm trying to bring some of the admin functionality to a custom front end in WordPress. Questions of security and pragmatism of this aside, is there an available hook to trigger wp_update_core outside of the admin?